# Should I use "either" or "neither" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Thinking of it, Mary didn't seem to fear anything. Perhaps, also/neither death.

What's the correct alternative and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use *also* to add to a positive set:

> Mary was afraid of spiders, snakes, and dogs.  She was **also** afraid of heights.

You would use *either* to add to a negative set:

> Mary was**n't** afraid of spiders, snakes, or dogs.  She was**n't** afraid of heights, **either**.

But in your example, you aren't adding to a set.  Instead, you're picking out an extreme example and emphasizing it.  For this, you should use *even*:

> Thinking of it, Mary didn't seem to fear anything.  Perhaps **not even** death.

Because the set of *everything/anything* already includes death, you can't use *also* or *either*, or the negative *neither*.